# spring security 4 custom login page

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I would like to create custom pure html/js login page in Spring Security.
I use Spring Boot 1.2.5.RELEASE
I defined an application and configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("a").password("a").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http
            .csrf().disable() // DISABLED CSRF protection to make it easier !
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/login.html").permit
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login.html")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

My login page looks like that (copied from default page!)

```
<html><head><title>Login Page</title></head><body onload='document.f.username.focus();'>
<h3>Login with Username and Password</h3><form name='f' action='/login' method='POST'>
<table>
<tr><td>User:</td><td><input type='text' name='username' value=''></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type='password' name='password'/></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Login"/></td>    </tr>
</table>
</form></body></html>
```

But I still have: AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE

Is it possible to create pute html login page (without jsp, thymeleaf, etc.) ?
What do I do wrong in my code ?

Answer (score 1):

You configured your login page to be at `/login.html` (using `loginPage("/login.html")`). This will also change the location to which you need to post the credentials to login. The documentation states:

> If "/authenticate" was passed to this method [`loginPage(String)`] it update the defaults as
>   shown below:
>
> - /authenticate GET - the login form
> - /authenticate POST - process the credentials and if valid authenticate the user
> - /authenticate?error GET - redirect here for failed authentication attempts
> - /authenticate?logout GET - redirect here after successfully logging out

In order to make the login work, you need to make `login.html` post the credentials to `/login.html` instead of `/login`.

Comment: from javadoc for the class: org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity
method:
public FormLoginConfigurer<HttpSecurity> formLogin() throws Exception
you can read: 
.usernameParameter(..) default is username
.passwordParameter(..) default is password
.loginProcessingUrl(..); default is /login with an HTTP post
I didn't modified this values.

Comment: You are right, those are the defaults of `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`. What are you doing exactly that results in an `AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE`? Can you post debug logs of `org.springframework.security`?

Comment: In the logs I just have:
2015-07-24 12:19:27.762  INFO 17134 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.b.a.audit.listener.AuditListener     : AuditEvent [timestamp=Fri Jul 24 12:19:27 CEST 2015, principal=anonymousUser, type=AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE, data={type=org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException, message=Access denied}]

Comment: Please enable debug logging for Spring Security by setting 'logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG' in your application.properties.

Comment: Here you can find all logs:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1D190nWa8R_RfCHADxQE9BlRfJs9_ZuGn6z2scGiyGF0/pub

Comment: From the logs I see that you try to authenticate against `j_spring_security_check`. As we already established, that won't work with the default Java Configuration. Please double check that you are actually using the `login.html` posted in your question and that it posts to `/login`.

Comment: I am sorry, I've forgotten to change fields after your first advice, I fixed it and now logs looks like that: 
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1-uVVgkjsSc7Adi4c7UXoiSqWR0WG27JsfnLhb-BGtEo/pub

Comment: Wow, you are right. Thank you very much ! 
I would like to comment ".csrf().disable()"and send this request by JavaScript. 
How can I find "_csrf" token using JavaScript ? 
(should I create a new question ?)

Comment: Glad I could help! Please create another question for the CSRF token. And if this answer solved your problem, I would be happy if you accepted it :-)

Comment: Are you still having trouble with the login page? If not, please accept this answer so that others may also benefit from it.